# Not able reach Internet in VM via another VM (vmware)

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

**VM-1(CentOS7)**

```
eht0-10.10.10.10/24           Gateway:0.0.0.0
eth1-Bridged Network to wlan0
eth2-192.168.3.10/24          Gateway:0.0.0.0
```

**VM-2(Ubuntu14)**

```
eth0-10.10.10.11/24               Gateway:0.0.0.0
eth1-192.168.2.11/24              Gateway:0.0.0.0
eth2-192.168.3.11/24              Gateway:192.168.3.10
```

**VM-3(Ubuntu14)**

```
eth0-10.10.10.12/24                   Gateway:0.0.0.0
eth1-192.168.2.12/24                  Gateway:0.0.0.0
eth2-192.168.3.12/24                  Gateway:192.168.3.10
```

So, `VM2` and `VM-3` has default gateway to `VM-1`. I'm able to `ping 8.8.8.8` from `VM-1`. Able to `ping 192.168.3.10` from `VM-2` and `VM-3`.

But, I can't `ping 8.8.8.8` from `VM-3` and `VM-2`.

I did `NAT` commands on `VM-1`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE`

`sudo iptables -t filter -D INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`

`sudo iptables -t filter -D FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`

I checked with `tcpdumps -n -i eth2` on `VM-1` while `VM-2` is pinging to 8.8.8.8. The packets are coming from `VM-1`

So, did I miss anything?

*And one more thing is I did static ip in `/etc/network/interfaces`(In same way as CentOS also!), but after sometimes I'm not getting the IP for an interface (In Ubuntu)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.3.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Or even this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```